# Traer de base de datos a RadioButton

Tags: c#, .net

Saludos, tengo un datagridview con un botón de editar. Cuando pulsas a editar, el botón trae todos los datos de la base de datos al formulario llamado Actualizar.

Con los campos de textos es simple. Pude hacer la conversión de este modo:

```
    private void dgv_buscar_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex !=1)
        {
            if (dgv_buscar.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString().Equals("editar"))
            {
                var registro = new Clases.Registro();
                var cedula = dgv_buscar.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                var tabla = registro.BUSCARCEDULA(cedula);
                var f = new Actualizar();
                f.Show();
                if (tabla.Rows.Count==1)
                {
                    Actualizar.Myform.txtNombre.Text = tabla.Rows[0]["NOMBRE"].ToString();
                    Actualizar.Myform.txtApellido.Text = tabla.Rows[0]["APELLIDO"].ToString();
                    Actualizar.Myform.txtCedula.Text = tabla.Rows[0]["CEDULA"].ToString();
                    Actualizar.Myform.txtDireccion.Text = tabla.Rows[0]["DIRECCION"].ToString();
                    Actualizar.Myform.txtTelefono.Text = tabla.Rows[0]["TELEFONO"].ToString();
                    Actualizar.Myform.txtCelular.Text = tabla.Rows[0]["CELULAR"].ToString();
                    Actualizar.Myform.txtconversion.Text= tabla.Rows[0]["FCONVERSION"].ToString();
                    Actualizar.Myform.txtbautismo.Text = tabla.Rows[0]["FBAUTISMO"].ToString();
                    Actualizar.Myform.txtmiembro.Text = tabla.Rows[0]["FMIEMBRO"].ToString();
                    Actualizar.Myform.comboBox1.Text = tabla.Rows[0]["CONGREGACION"].ToString();
                    Actualizar.Myform.txtnacimiento.Text = tabla.Rows[0]["F_NACIMIENTO"].ToString();
```

Ahora bien, necesito traer los resultados que inserté en la base de datos a través de un radio, de nuevo al radio y no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

Para insertar en un radio, utilicé dos formas:

1. Declarar un string con el nombre del RadioButton, y en caso de que este radio sea seleccionado, insertar el evento resultado checked changed dentro de el.

Ejemplo:

String genero:
genero = "M";

2. El otro metodo que usé fue declarar en la base de datos el campo como bool, e introducir a la base que si el radio es seleccionado, introducir true o false.

Esta es la forma en que introduje a la base de datos:

```
      private void btm_actualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime nacimiento = DateTime.Parse(txtnacimiento.Text);
        DateTime conversion = DateTime.Parse(txtconversion.Text);
        DateTime bautismo = DateTime.Parse(txtbautismo.Text);
        DateTime miembro = DateTime.Parse(txtmiembro.Text);
        var registrar = new Clases.Registro(txtCedula.Text, txtNombre.Text, txtApellido.Text, txtTelefono.Text, txtDireccion.Text, genero, ecivil, hijos, txtCelular.Text, nacimiento);
        registrar.registrar();
        var info = new Clases.InfoEcle(txtCedula.Text, conversion, bautismo, espiritusanto, bautizoiglesia, miembro, cajatexto);
        info.registrar();
        registrar.ListarDataGrid(Vistas.Buscar.FrmBuscar.dgv_buscar);
    }
    private void rdhombre_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        genero = "H";
    }

    private void rdmujer_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        genero = "M";
    }
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres al `RadioButton`?, además ¿qué tipo de dato guardas para luego colocarlo en el RadioButton?

Comment: Estoy guardando un string "H" o "M", como puedes ver en el codigo que puse arriba.

En otros radio, guardo un true or false, ya que son bool

Comment: Que tal algo como esto: `Actualizar.Myform.rdhombre.Checked = tabla.Rows[0]["GENERO"].ToString().Equals("H") ? true : false;` , y puedes hacer lo mismo si es para Mujer, aunque cuando un RadioButton esta seleccionado los demás no lo estarán, esto bastaría...

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que estuve mirando tienes dos radioButtons uno es el que infiere el genero del Hombre a lo que tu pones "H" y el del genero de la Mujer que es la M, puedes hacer dos cosas a la hora de guardar esa informacion en la base de datos 1 guardarla como un varchar(1), o guardarlo como bit o boolean. Si lo guardas como boolean solo tienes que poner a la hora de salvar en vez de pasar el género poner (genero == "H") haciendo que tome el valor booleano true si es hombre y falso si es mujer y a la hora de mostrar los datos extraidos de la base de datos solo tienes ke hacer lo siguiente.

```
   Actualizar.Myform.rdhombre.Checked = tabla.Rows[0]["GENERO"].ToBoolean();
   Actualizar.Myform.rdmujer.Checked = !Actualizar.Myform.rdhombre.Checked;
   /*De esta forma si la persona es un hombre activas el radio button
     perteneciente a ese genero y desactivas el del genero contrario y si 
     es al reves tambien funciona, ya que asigna el valor contrario.*/
```

No se si la funcion ToBoolean exista a lo mejor es ToBool pero bueno ahi te dejo mi aporte, si todavia quieres seguir con el tipo de dato string lo haces de esta otra forma

```
   Actualizar.Myform.rdhombre.Checked = tabla.Rows[0]["GENERO"].ToString().Equals("H");
   //Esta línea se mantiene en ambos casos
   Actualizar.Myform.rdmujer.Checked = !Actualizar.Myform.rdhombre.Checked;
```

Comment: Está demás que indicas tu respuesta diciendo `ToBoolean` debido a que no existe, a menos que implementes un método de extensión e indiques en la código.

Comment: Sencillo, si no kieres enredarte con una extensión, si el indexados a tabla.Rows[0]["GENERO"] devuelve un object solo tienes que castearlo a (bool).